# how to check the size of an array during compile time

Tags: c++, compilation, static-assert

I have this code:

```
template<char... Ts>
class  myIDClass 
{
protected:
       std::vector<uint8_t> m_ID = { Ts... };

public:
       std::vector<uint8_t> getID()
        {
             return m_ID;
        }
}
```

and I can use it in this way:

```
class   MyClass: myIDClass<'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'>
{
  // some code here
}

MyClass mc;
```

But I want to  make sure that the person that uses myIDClass enter exactly 8 character to enter as template parameter to the class. How can I do during compilation?

Is there anyway that I can do this using of static_asset?

Comment: why do you use `std::vector` and not `std::array` if the size should be a compile time constant?

Comment: What's wrong with the old-fashioned way: create a constructor taking 8 arguments?

Comment: ...and why do you use a variadic parameter list when you dont want it to be variadic ? ;)

Comment: @tobi303 How to use an array instead of a vector?

Comment: @Bathsheba old fashioned is slow as the initialization of vector (or array) is done during run time and not compile time.

Comment: simply replace your `std::vector` with an `std::array` of a fixed size of 8. I am not familiar with brace initalization, but perhaps `std::array` accepts only initializers of the right size, if not then I would still use `array` instead of `vector` even if the only consequence would be to give it the right name

Comment: @tobi303 How to use a fixed size parameter? The idea is to send a buffer that has 8 byte of data? the 8 byte is fixed at compile time and should be changed at anytime later when somebody uses the class.

Comment: sry, not sure if I understand you correctly.... `array`s second template parameter is its size, that needs to be fixed at compile time. If you know it is 8 then just use an array of size 8

Comment: @tobi303 I tried to use an array (old fashioned uint8_t m_ID[]={ Ts... };) but it don;t compiled.

Comment: I am talking about `std::array` not c-style arrays

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use `std::array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
template<char... Ts>
class myIDClass
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == 8, "myIDClass needs 8 template arguments");

    // ...
```

However, since you know at compile time that you want exactly 8 values, you can use `std::array` instead:

```
#include <array>
// ...

template<char... Ts>
class  myIDClass 
{
    // The assertion is not actually needed, but you might still want to keep
    // it so that the user of the template gets a better error message.
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == 8, "myIDClass needs 8 template arguments");

protected:
    std::array<uint8_t, 8> m_ID = { Ts... };

public:
    std::array<uint8_t, 8> getID()
    {
        return m_ID;
    }
};
```

In this case, you don't need the `static_assert` anymore. However, the error message the user of the template gets when not using exactly 8 arguments can be confusing. The assertion in this case helps with giving out a better error message.